# disable tabbing on document but enable input tabbing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added the following code to my site to prevent tabbing, this applies to the whole document. Problem is that this obviously disables all tabbing throughout the site, how can I add a rule in to allow inputs to be tabbed? I tried adding .not('input') but this doesnt seem to work.

```
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  
            objEvent.preventDefault(); 
        }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: IMHO Its not a good idea.  By disabling tabbing you break the browsers default behavior.  Many people use tabbing for browsing as they may be accustom to using keyboard command instead of mouse.  In addition, the blind rely on this heavily with screen readers.

Comment: hi john, i totally agree with you on this but for this particular site its a requirement but im with you on your views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value of `document.activeElement.tagName`.

If nothing is selected, `document.activeElement` will be the `body` tag in FireFox, Chrome, and the `html` tag in IE 7/8/9.

```
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  
            if (document.activeElement.tagName != 'INPUT')
                objEvent.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyup event properly also sends a target with it.

objEvent.target should return the current target the user is at.

So checking up on if the target is an input field then ignore the preventDefault...

**Edit:** Not sure if this is gonna work. "wsanville" method looks more legit.